# firebasestorage not being recognized even thought I have the imports and dependency in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

```
final userRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(userPath);
```

This line has an error where FirebaseStorage has the error, even though I installed the dependency and imported firebase storage:

> Undefined name 'FirebaseStorage'

It was working before as I was able to access FirebaseStorage but not anymore

I tried running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and `flutter run`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal-but-complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so including the dependencies and imports that you have. I'd also recommend reading https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.